# Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, button

I want to create an app that will log all the notifications of the apps. I'm creating the button, but im getting *"Cannot be resolved or is not a field"*.

this is the activity_get_notification.xml

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/OKButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
    android:text="@string/ok" />
```

and this is the java code

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.notificationnotifier.R;

public class GetNotification extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_notification);

    Button OKButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OKButton);
     Intent getNotification = new Intent("com.example.notificationnotifier.monitorNotification");
    startActivity(getNotification);
}
```

And my androidmanifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.notificationnotifier"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationnotifier.GetNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.notificationnotifier.monitorNotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and this is the error message

```
[2013-02-04 01:18:52 - NotificationNotifier] W/ResourceType( 7432): Bad XML block: header size 60 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-02-04 01:18:52 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\layout\activity_get_notification.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/ok').
[2013-02-04 01:18:52 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\menu\activity_get_notification.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
[2013-02-04 01:20:23 - NotificationNotifier] W/ResourceType( 6764): Bad XML block: header size 85 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-02-04 01:20:23 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\layout\activity_get_notification.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/ok').
[2013-02-04 01:20:23 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\menu\activity_get_notification.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
[2013-02-04 01:24:18 - NotificationNotifier] W/ResourceType( 5092): Bad XML block: header size 147 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-02-04 01:24:18 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\layout\activity_get_notification.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/ok').
[2013-02-04 01:24:18 - NotificationNotifier] C:\Users\Trend\workspace\NotificationNotifier\res\menu\activity_get_notification.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
```

Comment: where are you getting that error?

Comment: please, provide full logcat

Comment: new Intent("com.example.notificationnotifier"); is your package, not an activity

Comment: make sure you are setting right layout for Activity here `setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_notification);` or u have a button with `OKButton` id in `activity_get_notification` layout ?

Comment: You've shown the layout.  What is the filename of it?

Comment: @StarsSky i posted the error message above. im not sure if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: Your layout is not compiling because you have problems with your strings.xml.  Please post the full contents of the layout and the full contents of strings.xml

Comment: @Simon yes. I added menu_settings in strings.xml and it solved the problem. thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in log :

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value
>   '@string/ok').

means you forget to add `ok` and `menu_settings`  strings in   `res/values/strings.xml` file . add it as :

```
<resources>
    <string name="ok">ok button</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">menu settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: adding menu_settings solved the problem. i just wonder why it kept on putting the blame to the OKButton. anyway, THANK YOU!!! :D

Comment: @srhsnl : most welcome friend . it possible you these to stings have some relation